# VBA EXCEL: Replacing character with only one double quote when exporting a .csv file

Tags: json, excel, vba, csv

Using excel vba, I export .csv files for a json-based application.

I have a formula that groups urls in a single column (see the resulting format below). Since Excel can't use double quotes in a formula, I use the **single quote character** in excel ('). Later, in the exported .csv, I replace this character with **double quotes character**, manually, using Notepad.

The column format in excel looks like this, which is appended text using simple &:

```
'{'https://www.url1.com': ['en/Url1'], 'https://www.url2.com': ['en/Url2']}'
```

Problem is, this column needs to look like this in the exported .csv:

```
    "{"https://www.url1.com": ["en/Url1"], "https://www.url2.com": ["en/Url2"]}"
```

I was trying to add a mechanism to replace the single quote automatically with double when exporting the .csv, but since double quote is an scape character in excel, I can't find **how to add only one double quote character using vba**.

How can I replace with a single double quote
Is it possible to add single double quotes using VBA?
Is there any way to add a single double quote (as text) in a formula?

Here is the .csv exporter VBA code I have:

```
Option Explicit
Sub SExportAsCSV()

Dim MyFileName As String
Dim CurrentWB As Workbook, TempWB As Workbook
Dim lr As Long, i As Long

Set CurrentWB = ActiveWorkbook
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy

Set TempWB = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
  .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With

'replace '
lr = TempWB.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

TempWB.Sheets(1).Range("BA2:BA" & lr).Replace What:="'", Replacement:="""", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

'  For i = 2 To lr
'
'        TempWB.Sheets(1).Range("BA" & i).Value = Replace(TempWB.Sheets(1).Range("BA" & i).Value, "'", """)
'
'    Next i
'end of replace '

MyFileName = CurrentWB.Path & "\" & Left(CurrentWB.Name, Len(CurrentWB.Name) - 5) & ".csv"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
TempWB.SaveAs Filename:=MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True

TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

End Sub

Comment: Can you use Replacement:=Chr(34) instead of """"?

Comment: Definitely not. Already tried this and does not work.

Comment: Just to clarify, with this you get double double quotes, instead of single double quotes, as needed.